# strptime, as.POSIXct and as.Date return unexpected NA

Tags: r, macos, datetime, strptime, r-faq

When I try to parse a timestamp in the following format: "Thu Nov 8 15:41:45 2012", only `NA` is returned.

I am using Mac OS X, R 2.15.2 and Rstudio 0.97.237. The language of my OS is Dutch: I presume this has something to do with it.

When I try `strptime`, `NA` is returned:

```
var <- "Thu Nov 8 15:41:45 2012"
strptime(var, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
# [1] NA
```

Neither does `as.POSIXct` work:

```
as.POSIXct(var, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
# [1] NA
```

I also tried `as.Date` on the string above but without `%H:%M:%S` components:

```
as.Date("Thu Nov 8 2012", "%a %b %d %Y")
# [1] NA
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think it is exactly as you guessed, `strptime` fails to parse your date-time string because of your locales. Your string contains both abbreviated weekday (`%a`) and abbreviated month name (`%b`). These time specifications are described in `?strptime`:

> **Details**
>
> `%a`: Abbreviated weekday name *in the current locale on this
>   platform*
>
> `%b`: Abbreviated month name *in the current locale on this platform*.
>
> "Note that abbreviated names are platform-specific (although the
>   standards specify that in the `C` locale they must be the first three
>   letters of the capitalized English name:"
>
> "Knowing what the abbreviations are is essential if you wish to use
>   `%a`, `%b` or `%h` as part of an input format: see the examples for
>   how to check."
>
> **See also**
>
> [...] `locales` to query or set a locale.

The issue of `locales` is relevant also for `as.POSIXct`, `as.POSIXlt` and `as.Date`.

From `?as.POSIXct`:

> **Details**
>
> If `format` is specified, remember that some of the format
>   specifications are locale-specific, and you may need to set the
>   `LC_TIME` category appropriately via `Sys.setlocale`. This most often
>   affects the use of `%b`, `%B` (month names) and `%p` (AM/PM).

From `?as.Date`:

> **Details**
>
> Locale-specific conversions to and from character strings are used
>   where appropriate and available. This affects the names of the days
>   and months.

---

Thus, if weekdays and month names in the string differ from those in the current locale, `strptime`, `as.POSIXct` and `as.Date` fail to parse the string correctly and `NA` is returned.

However, you may solve this issue by changing the `locales`:

```
# First save your current locale
loc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")

# Set correct locale for the strings to be parsed
# (in this particular case: English)
# so that weekdays (e.g "Thu") and abbreviated month (e.g "Nov") are recognized
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8")
# or
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C") 

#Then proceed as you intended
x <- "Thu Nov 8 15:41:45 2012" 
strptime(x, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
# [1] "2012-11-08 15:41:45"

# Then set back to your old locale
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", loc)
```

With my personal locale I can reproduce your error:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", loc)
# [1] "fr_FR.UTF-8"

strptime(var,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
# [1] NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Was just messing around with same problem, and found this solution to be much cleaner because there is no need to change any of system settings manually, because there is a wrapper function doing this job in the `lubridate` package, and all you have to do is set the argument `locale`:

```
date <- c("23. juni 2014", "1. november 2014", "8. marts 2014", "16. juni 2014", "12. december 2014", "13. august 2014")
df$date <- dmy(df$Date, locale = "Danish")
[1] "2014-06-23" "2014-11-01" "2014-03-08" "2014-06-16" "2014-12-12" "2014-08-13"
```

Comment: Regarding "_there is no need to change any of system settings_", please note that the `locale` argument in the `lubridate` functions is just a convenience wrapper of the steps outlined in the answer above: (1) save current locale, (2) change locale, (3) revert to original locale. Check the code [here](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/master/R/parse.r):  `orig_locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale); on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", orig_locale))`

Comment: or `locale = "da_DK"`