# Rails 4 Group by function not working

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following table

Employee

Fields are

- id
- annual_leave_total
- group_id (FK)

And I writing a simple sum group by query by stating getting a sum of annual_leave_totals grouped by group_id ie

```
Employee.select("department_id, sum(annual_leave_total)").group(:group_id)
```

But what I get instead in the console is the following

```
irb(main):010:0> Employee.select("group_id, sum(annual_leave_total)").group(:group_id)
 Employee Load (1.0ms)  SELECT group_id, sum(annual_leave_total) FROM "employees" GROUP     BY group_id
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Employee id: nil, group_id: 1>, #<Employee id: nil, group_id: 2>, #<Employee id: nil, group_id: 3>]>
```

Why is it returning this hash type of result? It's different to what expected in an actual sql query...

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: This is what I'm supposed to see

group_id | sum  
----------+------
        1 | 1275
        2 |  600
        3 |  450

Comment: Try using `employees = Employee.select("department_id, sum(annual_leave_total) as annual_leave_total").group(:group_id)` and access to this sum by doing: `employees.first.annual_leave_total`

Comment: I redid the code.  Employee.select("group_id as Department, sum(annual_leave_total) as annual_leave_total").group(:group_id)
  And now the results come back with my actual totals column!
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Employee id: nil, annual_leave_total: 1275>, #<Employee id: nil, annual_leave_total: 600>, #<Employee id: nil, annual_leave_total: 450>]>

Comment: But I'd find this bizzare that I have to explicit about my grouping functions in the select clause.  I mean in the actual sql world, you can opt out the column names when grouping aggregate functions.  But in ruby/rails, they seem very restricted on this type of flexibility? Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like I wrote in another question ([when i was using find_by_sql alias, i got confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956430/when-i-was-using-find-by-sql-alias-i-got-confused)), AREL simply tries to map your query to the `Employee model`. Since you start your query from the `Employee` class as a base, you will get an object of this type back.

In your query you only selected the `group_id`, which is an attribute of the class, and a sum of one of the attributes (but not the attribute itself!). Now keep in mind that what you printed out is simply a `to_s` representation of the `Employee` object which only knows about its own attributes you listed in your post. It doesn't know about an attribute called `sum(annual_leave_total)`, so it isn't printed.

However, the value can still be accessed through the attributes hash though by calling `employee.first.attributes`. The hash should include all of the class attributes (most as nil, as you didn't select them) as well as the additional ones. The sum value just doesn't have a getter since it's not an 'official' attribute of the class.