# How to convert date to format "yyyy-mm-dd" in R when input value can be of different formats

Tags: r, date

I can receive files where date can be in one of the two formats: "mm/dd/yyyy" or "yyyy-mm-dd". They are factors to start with. Irrespective of the date format i receive it in, i want to be able to convert them to 'Date' data type of format "yyyy-mm-dd". I have tried using

`df_1$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df_1$Date), format = "%Y-%m-%d")`

This works with the format "yyyy-mm-dd" but gives NA when input values are of format "mm/dd/yyyy". Similarly, other methods i have tried works for only one of these 2 formats.
I need it to work for both.

Below i have posted code for creating the datasets and replicating the issue.

```
df_1 <- structure(list(Text.Identifier = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 1838L), Date = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                      2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("5/18/2016", "7/12/2015", "8/29/2016"
                                                                      ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Text.Identifier", "Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                        -4L))

df_2 <- structure(list(Text.Identifier = 1:4, Date = structure(c(5L, 
                                                     5L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("2015-07-12", "2016-05-01", "2016-05-05", 
                                                                             "2016-05-09", "2016-05-12", "2016-05-18", "2016-08-01", "2016-08-19", 
                                                                             "2016-08-29", "2016-09-20"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Text.Identifier", 
                                                                                                                                         "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

df_1$Date <- as.Date(df_1$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df_2$Date <- as.Date(df_2$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
View(df_1)
View(df_2)
```

Comment: Check out `parse_date_time` in the `lubridate` package. Also it worth re-orienting your thinking from excel where exact order mattered into a more R way of thinking where it is more important what class you are dealing with.

Comment: Potential duplicate from 7 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/40940164/5472462 that answers this question very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to automatically apply correct as.Date format in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940016/function-to-automatically-apply-correct-as-date-format-in-r)

Comment: @vincentmajor That doesn't look like a dupe to me. I don't think that `lubridate` can handle dates with mixed MDY / YMD order.

Comment: @RHertel I believe it can. `library(lubridate); data = c("01-12-2000", "02-11-2001", "2016-06-20", "2016-12-05"); parse_date_time(data, c('dmy', 'ymd'))`

Comment: @vincentmajor Agreed. One will need to wrap the output into `as.Date()`, but yes, if the possible formats are specified, then it works. In my opinion, the need for such hard-coding of the formats means that the `lubridate` library cannot really handle the different dates, in the sense that it needs assistance from the user. However, the `anytime` library can recognize virtually any date without any further input. It is more flexible and concise than the linked solution. I therefore think that it is better to refer to the `anytime` package than to the linked answer in this case.

Comment: @vincentmajor Thanks a lot. That worked.

Comment: @SurajTataPrasad You are welcome. I added an answer from my comment above. Go ahead and mark this question answered if it was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the `anydate()` function from the `anytime` library. It is better suited to this case than `lubridate`'s `parse_date_time()`, since it recognizes the dates without requiring any user input concerning the order of the entries, like `ymd` or `dmy`. Furthermore, there is no problem if the data is stored as factors.

Here's an example:

```
my_dates <- c("2015-07-12", "2016-05-01", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-09", 
 "2016-05-12", "2016-05-18", "2016-08-01", "2016-08-19", "2016-08-29",
 "2016-09-20", "5/18/2016", "7/12/2015", "8/29/2016")
my_dates <- as.factor(my_dates)
library(anytime)
anydate(my_dates)
# [1] "2015-07-12" "2016-05-01" "2016-05-05" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-12" "2016-05-18"
# [7] "2016-08-01" "2016-08-19" "2016-08-29" "2016-09-20" "2016-05-18" "2015-07-12"
#[13] "2016-08-29
```

One can verify that the class of the output is indeed `Date`

```
class(anydate(my_dates))
#[1] "Date"
```

whereas another posted solution yields a POSIX object with unnecessary time zone information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the only two date formats are "mm/dd/yyyy" or "yyyy-mm-dd", this should work. This solution uses grep to find a forward slash in the dates, and converts those dates from "mm/dd/yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-dd".

Here is an example:

```
dates <- data.frame(date = c("2015-11-01", "12/12/2016", "1992-05-28", "03/05/2011"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dates$date[grep("/", dates$date)] <- as.character(as.Date(dates$date[grep("/", dates$date)], "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: You are using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, but the OP stated that the dates are stored as factors.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my comment as an answer so we can mark this question answered.

The `lubridate` package is smart enough to choose between different date separators and also different date orders.

```
library(lubridate)
data = c("01-12-2000", "02-11-2001", "2016-06-20", "2016-12-05")
parse_date_time(data, c('dmy', 'ymd'))

## returns
## [1] "2000-12-01 UTC" "2001-11-02 UTC" "2016-06-20 UTC" "2016-12-05 UTC"
```