# split date and time in different columns of dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe in R

```
ID       Date1              Date2       

1        21-03-16 8:36      22-03-16 12:36
1        23-03-16 9:36      24-03-16 01:36
1        22-03-16 10:36     25-03-16 11:46
1        23-03-16 11:36     28-03-16 10:16
```

My desired dataframe is

```
ID    Date1        Date1_time    Date2          Date2_time
1     2016-03-21   08:36:00      2016-03-22     12:36:00
1     2016-03-23   09:36:00      2016-03-24     01:36:00
1     2016-03-22   10:36:00      2016-03-25     11:46:00
1     2016-03-23   11:36:00      2016-03-28     10:16:00
```

I can do this individually using `strptime` like following

```
df$Date1 <- strptime(df$Date1, format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
df$Date1_time <-  strftime(df$Date1 ,format="%H:%M:%S")
df$Date1 <- strptime(df$Date1, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

But,I have many date columns to convert like above. How can I write function in R which will do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`dplyr::mutate_at`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) to operate on multiple columns. See [`select helpers`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_helpers.html) for more info on efficiently specifying which columns to operate on.

Then you can use [`lubridate`](http://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) and [`hms`](https://github.com/tidyverse/hms) for date and time functions.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)


df <- readr::read_csv(
'ID,Date1,Date2
1,"21-03-16 8:36","22-03-16 12:36"
1,"23-03-16 9:36","24-03-16 01:36"
1,"22-03-16 10:36","25-03-16 11:46"
1,"23-03-16 11:36","28-03-16 10:16"'
)

df

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      ID          Date1          Date2
#>   <int>          <chr>          <chr>
#> 1     1  21-03-16 8:36 22-03-16 12:36
#> 2     1  23-03-16 9:36 24-03-16 01:36
#> 3     1 22-03-16 10:36 25-03-16 11:46
#> 4     1 23-03-16 11:36 28-03-16 10:16

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Date1, Date2), dmy_hm) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Date1, Date2), funs("date" = date(.), "time" = as.hms(.))) %>% 
  select(-Date1, -Date2)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>      ID Date1_date Date2_date Date1_time Date2_time
#>   <int>     <date>     <date>     <time>     <time>
#> 1     1 2016-03-21 2016-03-22   08:36:00   12:36:00
#> 2     1 2016-03-23 2016-03-24   09:36:00   01:36:00
#> 3     1 2016-03-22 2016-03-25   10:36:00   11:46:00
#> 4     1 2016-03-23 2016-03-28   11:36:00   10:16:00
```

Comment: When I run your code it give me `Error in as.fun_list(.funs, .env = parent.frame(), ...) : 
  object 'as_datetime' not found`

Comment: Did you run `library(lubridate)` first?

Comment: I replaced it with `as_date` but it gives me some weird formatted date `0021-03-16` and time as `00:00:00`

Comment: Hey, sorry I totally missed that it was dmy not ymd format. I've changed the first function from `as_datetime()` to `dmy_hm()` and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` for manipulation:

```
convertTime <- function(x)as.POSIXct(x, format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M')

df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(Date1, Date2), convertTime) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate_all(funs("date"=as.Date(.), "time"=format(., "%H:%M:%S")))


# Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
# Groups: ID [1]
# 
#      ID               Date1               Date2 Date1_date Date2_date Date1_time Date2_time
#   <int>              <dttm>              <dttm>     <date>     <date>      <chr>      <chr>
# 1     1 2016-03-22 12:36:00 2016-03-22 12:36:00 2016-03-22 2016-03-22   12:36:00   12:36:00
# 2     1 2016-03-24 01:36:00 2016-03-24 01:36:00 2016-03-23 2016-03-23   01:36:00   01:36:00
# 3     1 2016-03-25 11:46:00 2016-03-25 11:46:00 2016-03-25 2016-03-25   11:46:00   11:46:00
# 4     1 2016-03-28 10:16:00 2016-03-28 10:16:00 2016-03-28 2016-03-28   10:16:00   10:16:00
```

Comment: by running above code it gives me following error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` I do not want to groupby by ID. Want it to run for every row

Comment: Don't worry about the `group_by`. It's not going to affect the mutate in this case, and it's used as a way to bypass the identifier variable, so that you do not need to specify all variables (e.g. `Date1` to `DateX`) with the `mutate_all` function. As for the error, can you please share what is the data-structure of your data.frame?

Comment: Here's [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755425/what-are-the-standard-unambiguous-date-formats) associated with the error you'd encountered. For the last line, if you replace `"date"=as.Date(.)` with `"date"=format(., "%Y-%m-%d")`, do you still get the error?

Comment: It gives `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : invalid 'trim' argument`

Comment: I suspect there are some issues with the format of your whole data-set, which I doubt I could help you further with only the sample data above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, you can try this may be help using **strsplit**

```
x <- df$Date1    
y = t(as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(x),' ')))
    row.names(y) = NULL

    # store splitted data into new columns 
    df$date <- y[,1] # date column
    df$time <- y[,2] # time column
```