# Why is my R Code giving me this specific error message during a transform of the Date Column?

Tags: r, date

I am using R in RStudio. My dataset comes from a csv file with only 2 variables, namely Date and Price (extract shown below):

```
Date          Price
2016-12-01     25
2016-12-02     16
2016-12-03     20
```

and the data goes on till 2017-07-13

Here are R Codes:

```
test1.data <- read.csv("test1.csv", as.is=TRUE)
test1.data <- transform(test1.data,
                    week = as.POSIXlt(Date)$yday %/% 7 + 1,
                    wday = as.POSIXlt(Date)$wday,
                    year = as.POSIXlt(Date)$year + 1900)
```

When I execute the codes, I get the following error message:

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(Date) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

I had a look at this question: [What are the “standard unambiguous date” formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755425/what-are-the-standard-unambiguous-date-formats)

I am new to R and I am having a hard time trying to figure out the solution.
How do I correct this?

Comment: There is probably some element that doesn't have a nice format or is associated with a nonexistent date. Maybe try `filter(test1.data, is.na(as.POSIXlt(Date)))` to see.

Comment: I ran this code and got the following error messages:
test1check<-filter(test1.data, is.na(as.POSIXlt(Date)))
Error in as.POSIXlt(Date) : object 'Date' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: D'oh. Okay, guess mine was a bad suggestion... Hm, maybe filter with `!grepl("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", Date)` instead. Hard to diagnose without a concrete example. General guidance is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using `strftime` works for you:

```
# create Data
test1.data <- data.frame(Date=c('2016-12-01','2016-12-02','2016-12-03'),Price=c(25,16,20))

test1.data <- transform(test1.data,
  week = strftime(Date,format = '%V'),
  wday = strftime(Date,format = '%a'),
  year = strftime(Date,format = '%Y'))
```

Output:

```
> test1.data
        Date Price week wday year
1 2016-12-01    25   48  Thu 2016
2 2016-12-02    16   48  Fri 2016
3 2016-12-03    20   48  Sat 2016
```

In this case I assumed you want week of the year, weekday and year. There's many many more options which you can see at `?strftime`

Comment: Thanks but I am getting the same error message:
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: The values in your `Date` column all strictly follow the _YYYY-MM-DD_ scheme? Because that is definitely unambiguous. Did you try and run my code?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. There were some dates which did not follow the yyyy-mm-dd format!