# Why is my time formatting unsuccessful in R

Tags: r, strptime

```
strptime('16/Oct/2005:07:51:00',format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
#[1] NA
```

My `R` version is **3.0.2** (2013-09-25) and :

```
strptime('16/2005:07:51:00',format='%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
#[1] "2005-11-16 07:51:00"
```

`"Oct"` and `%b` is unsuccessful, and the following is also unsuccessful:

```
strptime("Mon Oct 28 00:19:35 +0800 2013", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
#[1] NA

sessionInfo()
#R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
#Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#locale: 
#[1] LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=zh_TW.UTF-8       
#[4] LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=zh_TW.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN.UTF-8   
#[7] LC_PAPER=zh_TW.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
#[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_TW.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

#attached base packages:
#[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#[1] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: All of those commands worked fine on my R installation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is localized problem


Comment: I expect the answer is time.

Comment: @fainle copy/pasting from your code the last example works just fine for me. Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` into your question. I don't agree with the close vote yet. We don't yet know what the problem is (but it is likely to be localised).

Comment: @SimonO101 strptime("Tue Nov 12 00:19:35 +0800 2013", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y") the result is NA, but, I expect the answer is 2013-11-12 00:19:35

Comment: Right. I get the result you obviously expect. Which is why I am *asking* you to edit in the output from `sessionInfo()`. I suspect that you have overwritten your `strptime` function or you have loaded a package that is overwriting it (possibly). If you don't give people more info this will get closed as too localised.

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=zh_TW.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=zh_TW.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=zh_TW.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_TW.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2

Comment: @SimonO101 ok, i output the sessionInfo()

Comment: You are getting NA values due to the your locale, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-in-r-works-then-stops-working-and-then-works-again) for solution