# Chr to date in R

Tags: r, date

How can I convert a chr value such as: `"Thu Jul 24 11:58:12 CEST 2014"` to Date format in R?

I've tried:

`dataset$acquiredDateTime = strptime(dataset$acquiredDateTime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")`

but it returns:

```
acquiredDateTime : POSIXt, format NA NA NA NA ...
```

Even as. Date:

`dataset$acquiredDateTime = as.Date(dataset$acquiredDateTime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

is not working. It returns:

```
acquiredDateTime : Date, format NA NA NA NA ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
 v1 <- "Thu Jul 24 11:58:12 CEST 2014"

 strptime(gsub("CEST", "", v1), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", tz="CEST")
 #[1] "2014-07-24 11:58:12 CEST"
```

Comment: on my system it works like this: > v1 <- "Thu Jul 24 11:58:12 CEST 2014"
> strptime(gsub("CEST", "", v1), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", tz="CEST")
[1] NA

Comment: @Ricky Seems like both (mdsumner) the solutions that are working are not working at your end.  Check if this has anything to do with <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-in-r-works-then-stops-working-and-then-works-again>

Comment: Yes, I fixed it with Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8") thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the CEST string in your template, or process it out:

```
x="Thu Jul 24 11:58:12 CEST 2014"
strptime(x, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S CEST %Y")
```

[1] "2014-07-24 11:58:12 UTC"

I don't have experience with interpreting timezones for input.

Comment: Ok, explain me that: 
> x="Thu Jul 24 11:58:12 CEST 2014"
> strptime(x, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S CEST %Y")
[1] NA

Comment: What is your locale? Perhaps those calendar tokens are not local

Comment: I've fixed it, the error was actually in my locale. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly fine for me.

```
strptime("Thu Jul 24 11:58:12 CEST 2014", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2014-07-24 11:58:12 IST"
```

EDIT 1: Ok, I just saw the "CEST" part. Let me update the answer in a bit.

EDIT 2: Other answers have covered it.