# how to convert many date-time formats to one format

Tags: r

I have a column as `dt` in my `Dataframe` as below

`dt`

```
01-Jan-2017 12:00:00
12/01/2017   01:15:00
13-Sep-97    21:00:00
20 August 2017 22:00:00
12/19/17   01:15:00
2/4/2017    05:18:00
```

How to get R date time format in R_dt column

```
   dt                         R_dt
01-Jan-2017 12:00:00         2017-01-01 12:00:00
12/01/2017   01:15:00        2017-12-01 01:15:00
13-Sep-97    21:00:00        1997-09-13 21:00:00
20 August 2017 22:00:00      2017-08-20 22:00:00
12/19/17   01:15:00          2017-12-19 01:15:00
2/4/2017    05:18:00         2017-02-04 05:18:00
```

I have tried using - `strftime(mydf$date,"%d/%m/%Y")`- which throws error.

Comment: You could try the `lubridate::guess_formats`. Another option is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463523/convert-variable-with-mixed-date-formats-to-one-format-in-r).

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple formats, you need a function that automagically tries multiple formats. `anytime()` from my [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package is one such function:

```
R> dvec <- c("01-Jan-2017 12:00:00", "12/01/2017 01:15:00", "13-Sep-97 21:00:00", 
=            "20 August 2017 22:00:00", "12/19/17 01:15:00", "2/4/2017 05:18:00")
R> dvec
[1] "01-Jan-2017 12:00:00"    "12/01/2017 01:15:00"    
[3] "13-Sep-97 21:00:00"      "20 August 2017 22:00:00"
[5] "12/19/17 01:15:00"       "2/4/2017 05:18:00"      
R> anytime(dvec)
[1] "2017-01-01 12:00:00 CST" "2017-12-01 01:15:00 CST"
[3] NA                        "2017-08-20 22:00:00 CDT"
[5] NA                        NA                       
R>
```

You see that three fail: two use a two-digit year (format `%y`) which we don't support by default -- but for which we offer the ability to add formats via `addFormat()` so one can address this:

```
R> addFormats(c("%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))
R> anytime(dvec)
[1] "2017-01-01 12:00:00 CST" "2017-12-01 01:15:00 CST"
[3] "2097-09-13 21:00:00 CDT" "2017-08-20 22:00:00 CDT"
[5] "2017-12-19 01:15:00 CST" NA                       
R>
```

The last one fails because of single digit month and day -- and that is not parsed by the Boost code we use so I have no (easy) fix for it.

However, for reasons related to testing and comparison, we now also allow use of R's internal parser (via my package [RApiDatetime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RApiDatetime)) so you possible can post-process those:

```
R> anytime(dvec[6], useR=TRUE)
[1] "2017-02-04 05:18:00 CST"
R>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dirk , How to add format if the day has single digit as "12/1/2017 03:00:00"

Comment: Please re-read the last sentence of my original answer: You cannot.  But I added a possibility using R's parser--see the edited answer.

Comment: That will change with the next release at the end of the month / early next month which will cover a date like "12/1/2017" (and a datetime, of course).