# Use as.Date with tryFormats to parse dates with different formats

Tags: r, as.date

I have a variable with dates in a two different formats (`"%Y-%m-%d"` and `"%m/%d/%Y"`):

```
dput(df)
structure(1:8, .Label = c("2019-04-07", "2019-04-08", "2019-04-09", 
"2019-04-10", "7/29/2019", "7/30/2019", "7/31/2019", "8/1/2019"
), class = "factor")

# [1] 2019-04-07 2019-04-08 2019-04-09 2019-04-10 7/29/2019  7/30/2019  7/31/2019  8/1/2019  
# 8 Levels: 2019-04-07 2019-04-08 2019-04-09 2019-04-10 7/29/2019 7/30/2019 ... 8/1/2019
```

I try to parse the dates using `as.Date` with `tryFormats`

```
df <- as.character(df)
d <- as.Date(df, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

which converts the first format structure, but then returns `NA` for the second format structure. If I run the two formats separately, they look good though:

```
t1 <- as.Date(df, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
t2 <- as.Date(df, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

t1
# [1] "2019-04-07" "2019-04-08" "2019-04-09" "2019-04-10" NA          
# [6] NA           NA           NA          

t2
# [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           "2019-07-29"
# [6] "2019-07-30" "2019-07-31" "2019-08-01"
```

Any suggestions? I've looked through other responses, but haven't found any good tryFormats examples/questions that seem to address this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tryFormats` will only select *one* of the given formats. In your case you can convert them individually, as you have already done.

```
d <- as.Date(df,format="%Y-%m-%d")
d[is.na(d)]  <- as.Date(df[is.na(d)],format="%m/%d/%Y")
d
#[1] "2019-04-07" "2019-04-08" "2019-04-09" "2019-04-10" "2019-07-29"
#[6] "2019-07-30" "2019-07-31" "2019-08-01"
```

Comment: I've changed this to the correct answer as it more directly addresses my question. But all good answers. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(df)
```

If any of the formats are not present, use `addFormats()` to add that format and then apply the function

---

Or with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date(parse_date_time(df, c("ymd", "mdy")))
```

Comment: Well, holy moly. I had no idea that "anytime" package existed. Worked like a charm. Thanks! Any info on the tryFormats situations above?

Answer (score 2):

For base solution, you may try the following as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25464385/10820553):

```
> df
 #[1] "2019-04-07" "2019-04-08" "2019-04-09" "2019-04-10" "7/29/2019"  "7/30/2019"  
 #"7/31/2019"  "8/1/2019" 

fmts <- c("%Y-%m-%d","%m/%d/%Y")

as.Date(apply(outer(df, fmts, as.Date),1,na.omit),'1970-01-01')
#[1] "2019-04-07" "2019-04-08" "2019-04-09" "2019-04-10" "2019-07-29" "2019-07-30" "2019-07-31" "2019-08-01"
```