# Parse date column with mix of date formats

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have to combine several spreadsheets for my project and for some reason they all decided to enter the dates differently. Below is a sample of my data with all of the different date formats I got after reading in and combining all of the spreadsheets.

```
date
13-MAR-18
2018-08-05
43423
11-Mar-2019
10/16/2018
```

I'm trying to standardize everything and turn it into a yyyy-mm-dd format. This is my attempt below.

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(x = df$date,
                orders = c("Y m d, "d m y", "d B Y", "m/d/y", ),
                locale = "eng")
```

The problem is that the moment I reach a row with a different format, it stops working and just gives me NA's for the rest of the rows. How do I fix this?

Expected output

```
date        new_date
13-MAR-18   2018-03-13
2018-08-05  2018-08-05
43423       2018-11-19
11-Mar-2019 2019-03-11
10/16/2018  2018-10-16
```

Comment: Try using `parse_date_time` on each spreasheet before rowbinding them together.

Comment: Could you show the expected output.

Comment: I did want to try using parse_date_time before rowbinding them, but they had different formats even within each individual spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Row 2 was wrong!
As I mentioned one issue will be the order of the orders argument of parse_date_time:

Now it should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(parsedate)

df %>%   
  mutate(x = parse_date(date)) %>% 
  mutate(y = as.integer(str_extract(date, '^\\d+$')),
         y = as.Date(y, origin = "1899-12-30"),
         x = as.Date(x),
         y = coalesce(y,x)) %>% 
  select(date, new_date=y)

         date   new_date
1   13-MAR-18 2018-03-13
2  2018-08-05 2018-08-05
3       43423 2018-11-19
4 11-Mar-2019 2019-03-11
5  10/16/2018 2018-10-16
```

**First answer:**
In my point of view there are 3 challenges.

First of all it is difficult to feed the `orders` argument of `parse_date_time`. I think after applying arrange we could get some control.

Second, the integer type of date must be handled separately I think.

Finally, it is not clear which is month in "2018-08-05" it could be 8 or 5.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(x = parse_date_time(date, orders=c("mdy", "dmy", "ymd")),
         y = as.integer(str_extract(date, '^\\d+$')),
         y = as.Date(y, origin = "1899-12-30"),
         x = coalesce(x,y)) %>% 
  select(date, new_date=x)
```

```
 date   new_date
1  10/16/2018 2018-10-16
2 11-Mar-2019 2019-11-20
3   13-MAR-18 2018-03-13
4  2018-08-05 2018-08-05
5       43423 2018-11-19
Warning message:
Problem while computing `x = parse_date_time(date, orders =
c("mdy", "dmy", "ymd"))`.
i  1 failed to parse.
```

Comment: Actually, sorry it seems like this didn't work for the second row. The new date for 11-Mar-2019 should be 2019-03-11 not 2019-11-20. It seems like R thinks that the "11" is a month and not a day?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly now and no warning messages either. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Edit:

I've just realised that the conversion for "43423" to "2022-07-27 16:02:42" is incorrect using this approach (2022-07-27 is today's date), as further explained in the docs: https://github.com/gaborcsardi/parsedate

For this solution to work, you would need to handle 'integer' date formats first, then `parsedate()` the remaining dates. I think @TarJae's solution is the way to go.

### Original answer:

Here is a potential solution using the [parsedate package](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/parsedate/parsedate.pdf):

```r
#install.packages("parsedate")
library(parsedate)

df <- read.table(text = "date
13-MAR-18
2018-08-05
43423
11-Mar-2019
10/16/2018", header = TRUE)

df$date_parsed <- parse_date(df$date)
df
#>          date         date_parsed
#> 1   13-MAR-18 2018-03-13 00:00:00
#> 2  2018-08-05 2018-08-05 00:00:00
#> 3       43423 2022-07-27 16:02:42
#> 4 11-Mar-2019 2019-03-11 00:00:00
#> 5  10/16/2018 2018-10-16 00:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer there remain some challenges. The integer type and also '2018-08-05'.

Comment: Yes, absolutely - I think your approach of splitting the 'task' up into smaller chunks makes sense for handling these edge cases, +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer without using any package for reference.

```
dateV=c(
'13-MAR-18',
'2018-08-05',
'13-Jun-19')

#Note: "pat and formatUsed" is a lookup in pair
pat=c("[0-9]{2}-\\w\\w\\w-[0-9]{2}$", "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}")
formatUsed=c("%d-%B-%y", "%Y-%m-%d")

betterDateV=NULL

for (tryP in 1:length(pat))
{
  dx=which(grepl(pat[tryP], dateV))
  betterDateV[dx] = as.Date( dateV[dx]   , format= formatUsed[tryP] )
}
as.Date(as.numeric(betterDateV))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
as.Date(x, tryFormats = c()
```

See:

[Use as.Date with tryFormats to parse dates with different formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254390/use-as-date-with-tryformats-to-parse-dates-with-different-formats)

You need to specify the formats in c() in the best order to run it.

Comment: Your numerical date may be more of a challenge!  It may need to be added to as.Date("1970-01-01")... Which might need to use some logic rules