# strptime not recognizing %b/%B?

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to convert some dates in R with strptime.  I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-in-r-works-then-stops-working-and-then-works-again) and have set my locale so that it should work.  For example:

```
> Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "en_GB"
> format(Sys.time(), format="%B")
[1] "November"
```

However if I try to convert a month string, strptime returns NA, e.g.:

```
> strptime("November", format="%B")
[1] NA
```

I can run the example at the above link without any problem but if I simplify the example to just include the month, I get NA again.

```
> var <- "Thu Nov 8 15:41:45 2012"
> strptime(var, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
[1] "2012-11-08 15:41:45 GMT"
> strptime("Nov", format="%b")
[1] NA
```

What's going on here?  How can I parse a character month into a date object?

**EDIT** 
Thanks for the comments below.  To clarify, this also doesn't work:

```
> strptime("November 2011", format="%B %Y")
[1] NA
```

I would also expect `strptime` to fill in any missing fields with the current system time, as in `strptime("2011", format="%Y")`

Comment: "November" is not a date or a datetime. You need at least a year, month, and day to specify a date/datetime.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I thought the same way, but surprisingly, for almost all other cases, the missing parts of the date are "filled in". Try this: `strptime('11', '%M')`: `"2014-11-18 00:11:00 EST"`

Comment: @nograpes: that's unfortunate. I would prefer missing values/errors to "assume you meant it to be based on the current datetime". Odd that it's inconsistent and only does that for non-month values though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a bit confused by R's behaviour in the case of missing values in `strptime`. The documentation is clear enough:

> For strptime the input string need not specify the date completely: it
>   is assumed that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and an
>   unspecified year, month or day is the current one. Some components may
>   be returned as NA (but an unknown tzone component is represented by an
>   empty string).

But that doesn't always seem to be the case with months. Here is a particularly odd example:

```
strptime('Nov-01', '%B-%d')
[1] "2014-11-01"
strptime('2009-Nov', '%Y-%B')
[1] NA
```

An obvious workaround based on the above would be to make a simple function.

```
convert.months <- function(x) 
     strptime(paste(x,strftime(Sys.time(),'%d')), '%b %d')
```

Which is ugly, but it works:

```
convert.months(c("Nov","Dec"))
[1] "2014-11-18 EST" "2014-12-18 EST"
```

---

To be clear here are the test cases, which, according to my interpretation of the documentation, should all work:

```
strptime('11', '%m') # Fail
strptime('11-01', '%m-%d') # Works
strptime('2009-11', '%Y-%m') # Fail

strptime('Nov', '%b') # Fail
strptime('Nov-01', '%b-%d') # Works
strptime('2009-Nov', '%Y-%b') # Fail
```

Comment: Notably, the [IEEE specification for strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) is silent on the matter of not fully specified dates.

Comment: I'll have to go with this for the time being.  Not very satisfying though, is it?

Comment: Unsatisfying indeed. I suspect that this is a bug, but I wouldn't bring it up unless I had thoroughly read the source code.