# Convert from a timestamp containing abbreviated month and PM(in time) to Date

Tags: r

How can I convert from a timestamp like this:

```
aDate <- "9-Apr-17 10:00:00 PM"
convert <- as.Date(aDate, "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

Right now, convert gives `NA`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Are you sure that you defined `aDate` as above?

Comment: Because of [your `locale`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na)

Comment: you may want to use `as.IDate` or `as.POSIXct`

Comment: @Henrik:The locale fixes this!But it gives me only `"2017-04-09".I have to use `strptime(as.character(aDate), "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")` but then I have to convert to Date format which again shows only the date

Comment: @George I don't understand what mean by '_only_ "2017-04-09"'. Your title suggests that you wanted a `Date`.

Comment: @Henrik:Yes, but with time format also as I have in post (as.Date(aDate, "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")).Sorry for the incovenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem :

```
format(lubridate::dmy_hms(aDate), format = "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

> "09-04-17 22:00:00"

Comment: Hmm..It works!But it gives me ` "2017-04-09 22:00:03 UTC"` instead of ` "09-04-17 22:00:03 UTC"`.And I couldn't find a way to correct this.

Comment: Yes, I mean I can't find how to have first the date, then month, then year.