# Converting character string into Date

Tags: r, date, lubridate, strptime, as.date

I have a character vector with timestamps like the following:

```
Date <- c("Jul 31, 2017", "Jul 30, 2017", "Jul 29, 2017", "Jul 28, 2017")
```

And I'm trying to convert it into a date object type. I have tried several methods:

**as.Date**

```
Date <- as.Date(Date, format = "%B %d, %Y")
```

**strptime**

```
Date <- strptime(Date, format = "%B %d, %Y")
```

**mdy from lubridate**

```
Date <- mdy(Date)
```

But all of them returns NAs. I have also tried changing the format argument from `%B` to `%b` and the result is the same. Moreover, with `mdy` from `lubridate` parses the data in a different format than I'm expecting to. For example, if I do the run the next piece of code:

```
mdy("Jul 01, 2017")
```

I get as a result:

[1] "2017-01-20"

What can I do to convert it to a date in the proper format? Thank you.

Comment: It is all working fine with me `as.Date(Date, format = "%B %d, %Y")
#[1] "2017-07-31" "2017-07-30" "2017-07-29" "2017-07-28"`

Comment: It's weird, I get NA as a result.
    as.Date(Date, format = "%B %d, %Y")
    [1] NA NA NA NA

Comment: Can u try on a fresh session.  BTW, I am using R 3.4.2

Comment: Possibly a `locale` issue? [strptime, as.POSIXct and as.Date return unexpected NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na)

Comment: Yeah, works fine for me too ....

Comment: Yes, it was a `locale` problem. My locale was "Spanish_Spain.1252" so, after changing it to "C" it works perfectly. Thank you!