# R How to convert date format

Tags: r, date, datetime, type-conversion, format

I was looking to convert the following character string in a date format:

```
string <- '22APR2020'
date <- as.Date(string, format='%d%b%y')
date
>>> NA
```

Unfortunately, the result is `NA` and I need to convert it as a date in order to being able to calculate the time between two dates.

Thanks you

Comment: Seems like a locale issue. Check [strptime, as.POSIXct and as.Date return unexpected NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt always use `lubridate`:

```
string <- '22APR2020'
library(lubridate)
dmy(string)
[1] "2020-04-22"
```

here dmy is order of date, month and year appearance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `anytime` package:

```
library(anytime)
string <- '22APR2020'
anytime::anydate(string)
[1] "2020-04-22"
```

Comment: I am not sure which one between anytime and lubridate package is the most maintained over time. Right now, your answer is valid. Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your locale setting. It probably is set to a language where the fourth month is not abbreviated as "APR".

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "French")

string <- '22APR2020'
as.Date(string, format='%d%b%Y')
#[1] NA

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "German")
as.Date(string, format='%d%b%Y')
#[1] "2020-04-22"
```

Also, note the capital `Y` is used in the format string. It's important. `y` only refers to the decade (it would give the same result, by chance, for 2020, but give the wrong result for 2021).