# as.Date(date, format='%d %B %Y') turns '%d %B %Y' format column to NAs

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr

Given a sample csv file (to download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52lgg3e73cmh784/report1.csv?dl=0)), I read it with code below:

```
df <- read.csv(file = './report1.csv', header = TRUE)
head(df, 5)
```

Out:

[image]

As you can see, `date` columns is in format of `%d %B %Y` (based on the reference table from this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/08/date-formats-in-r/)) but with data type of `factor`.

So I try to use `as.Date(date, format='%d %B %Y')` to convert it to date format.

```
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date, format = '%d %B %Y'))
  # mutate(date=dmy(date))
```

But as you can see, all date values become `NA`s for that column. Meanwhile, `mutate(date=dmy(date))` works well.

[image]

Does someone could explain what's error in `as.Date(...)` code? Thanks.

Data:

```
dput(head(df, 5))
```

Out:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(31L, 43L, 55L, 67L, 79L), .Label = c("1 April 2020", 
"1 August 2020", "1 December 2020", "1 February 2021", "1 January 2021", 
"1 July 2020", "1 June 2020", "1 March 2021", "1 May 2020", "1 November 2020", 
"1 October 2020", "1 September 2020", "10 April 2020", "10 August 2020", 
"10 December 2020", "10 February 2021", "10 January 2021", "10 July 2020", 
"10 June 2020", "10 May 2020", "10 November 2020", "10 October 2020", 
"10 September 2020", "11 April 2020", "11 August 2020", "11 December 2020", 
"11 February 2021", "11 January 2021", "11 July 2020", "11 June 2020", 
"11 March 2020", "11 May 2020", "11 November 2020", "11 October 2020", 
"11 September 2020", "12 April 2020", "12 August 2020", "12 December 2020", 
"12 February 2021", "12 January 2021", "12 July 2020", "12 June 2020", 
"12 March 2020", "12 May 2020", "12 November 2020", "12 October 2020", 
"12 September 2020", "13 April 2020", "13 August 2020", "13 December 2020", 
"13 February 2021", "13 January 2021", "13 July 2020", "13 June 2020", 
"13 March 2020", "13 May 2020", "13 November 2020", "13 October 2020", 
"13 September 2020", "14 April 2020", "14 August 2020", "14 December 2020", 
"14 February 2021", "14 January 2021", "14 July 2020", "14 June 2020", 
"14 March 2020", "14 May 2020", "14 November 2020", "14 October 2020", 
"14 September 2020", "15 April 2020", "15 August 2020", "15 December 2020", 
"15 February 2021", "15 January 2021", "15 July 2020", "15 June 2020", 
"15 March 2020", "15 May 2020", "15 November 2020", "15 October 2020", 
"15 September 2020", "16 April 2020", "16 August 2020", "16 December 2020", 
"16 February 2021", "16 January 2021", "16 July 2020", "16 June 2020", 
"16 March 2020", "16 May 2020", "16 November 2020", "16 October 2020", 
"16 September 2020", "17 April 2020", "17 August 2020", "17 December 2020", 
"17 February 2021", "17 January 2021", "17 July 2020", "17 June 2020", 
"17 March 2020", "17 May 2020", "17 November 2020", "17 October 2020", 
"17 September 2020", "18 April 2020", "18 August 2020", "18 December 2020", 
"18 February 2021", "18 January 2021", "18 July 2020", "18 June 2020", 
"18 March 2020", "18 May 2020", "18 November 2020", "18 October 2020", 
"18 September 2020", "19 April 2020", "19 August 2020", "19 December 2020", 
"19 February 2021", "19 January 2021", "19 July 2020", "19 June 2020", 
"19 March 2020", "19 May 2020", "19 November 2020", "19 October 2020", 
"19 September 2020", "2 April 2020", "2 August 2020", "2 December 2020", 
"2 February 2021", "2 January 2021", "2 July 2020", "2 June 2020", 
"2 March 2021", "2 May 2020", "2 November 2020", "2 October 2020", 
"2 September 2020", "20 April 2020", "20 August 2020", "20 December 2020", 
"20 February 2021", "20 January 2021", "20 July 2020", "20 June 2020", 
"20 March 2020", "20 May 2020", "20 November 2020", "20 October 2020", 
"20 September 2020", "21 April 2020", "21 August 2020", "21 December 2020", 
"21 February 2021", "21 January 2021", "21 July 2020", "21 June 2020", 
"21 March 2020", "21 May 2020", "21 November 2020", "21 October 2020", 
"21 September 2020", "22 April 2020", "22 August 2020", "22 December 2020", 
"22 February 2021", "22 January 2021", "22 July 2020", "22 June 2020", 
"22 March 2020", "22 May 2020", "22 November 2020", "22 October 2020", 
"22 September 2020", "23 April 2020", "23 August 2020", "23 December 2020", 
"23 February 2021", "23 January 2021", "23 July 2020", "23 June 2020", 
"23 March 2020", "23 May 2020", "23 November 2020", "23 October 2020", 
"23 September 2020", "24 April 2020", "24 August 2020", "24 December 2020", 
"24 February 2021", "24 January 2021", "24 July 2020", "24 June 2020", 
"24 March 2020", "24 May 2020", "24 November 2020", "24 October 2020", 
"24 September 2020", "25 April 2020", "25 August 2020", "25 December 2020", 
"25 February 2021", "25 January 2021", "25 July 2020", "25 June 2020", 
"25 March 2020", "25 May 2020", "25 November 2020", "25 October 2020", 
"25 September 2020", "26 April 2020", "26 August 2020", "26 December 2020", 
"26 February 2021", "26 January 2021", "26 July 2020", "26 June 2020", 
"26 March 2020", "26 May 2020", "26 November 2020", "26 October 2020", 
"26 September 2020", "27 April 2020", "27 August 2020", "27 December 2020", 
"27 February 2021", "27 January 2021", "27 July 2020", "27 June 2020", 
"27 March 2020", "27 May 2020", "27 November 2020", "27 October 2020", 
"27 September 2020", "28 April 2020", "28 August 2020", "28 December 2020", 
"28 February 2021", "28 January 2021", "28 July 2020", "28 June 2020", 
"28 March 2020", "28 May 2020", "28 November 2020", "28 October 2020", 
"28 September 2020", "29 April 2020", "29 August 2020", "29 December 2020", 
"29 January 2021", "29 July 2020", "29 June 2020", "29 March 2020", 
"29 May 2020", "29 November 2020", "29 October 2020", "29 September 2020", 
"3 April 2020", "3 August 2020", "3 December 2020", "3 February 2021", 
"3 January 2021", "3 July 2020", "3 June 2020", "3 March 2021", 
"3 May 2020", "3 November 2020", "3 October 2020", "3 September 2020", 
"30 April 2020", "30 August 2020", "30 December 2020", "30 January 2021", 
"30 July 2020", "30 June 2020", "30 March 2020", "30 May 2020", 
"30 November 2020", "30 October 2020", "30 September 2020", "31 August 2020", 
"31 December 2020", "31 January 2021", "31 July 2020", "31 March 2020", 
"31 May 2020", "31 October 2020", "4 April 2020", "4 August 2020", 
"4 December 2020", "4 February 2021", "4 January 2021", "4 July 2020", 
"4 June 2020", "4 March 2021", "4 May 2020", "4 November 2020", 
"4 October 2020", "4 September 2020", "5 April 2020", "5 August 2020", 
"5 December 2020", "5 February 2021", "5 January 2021", "5 July 2020", 
"5 June 2020", "5 March 2021", "5 May 2020", "5 November 2020", 
"5 October 2020", "5 September 2020", "6 April 2020", "6 August 2020", 
"6 December 2020", "6 February 2021", "6 January 2021", "6 July 2020", 
"6 June 2020", "6 March 2021", "6 May 2020", "6 November 2020", 
"6 October 2020", "6 September 2020", "7 April 2020", "7 August 2020", 
"7 December 2020", "7 February 2021", "7 January 2021", "7 July 2020", 
"7 June 2020", "7 March 2021", "7 May 2020", "7 November 2020", 
"7 October 2020", "7 September 2020", "8 April 2020", "8 August 2020", 
"8 December 2020", "8 February 2021", "8 January 2021", "8 July 2020", 
"8 June 2020", "8 May 2020", "8 November 2020", "8 October 2020", 
"8 September 2020", "9 April 2020", "9 August 2020", "9 December 2020", 
"9 February 2021", "9 January 2021", "9 July 2020", "9 June 2020", 
"9 May 2020", "9 November 2020", "9 October 2020", "9 September 2020"
), class = "factor"), immobility = c(0.407428566, 1.553824969, 
3.033190503, 4.950250769, 7.40514975), cases = c(4.753590191, 
5.241747015, 5.690359454, 5.924255797, 6.150602768), icu = c(4.407936176, 
4.543724109, 4.72143235, 5.005429015, 5.280731862), deaths = c(0.922324625, 
1.315709119, 1.69429665, 2.057554016, 2.403912035)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide a `dput(head(df,20))` of your data ?

Comment: I cant seem to recreate this problem when I download the data from your provided link. Date imports as a character and correctly reformats to a date (even when I force it to a factor, then run the code).

Comment: I guess this is a `locale` issue that the month names in your local `locale` are not January, February, March, etc.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that converting month names depends on the locale, e.g. as I'm running on a German locale `as.Date("13 March 2020", format = '%d %B %Y')` returns NA, while using the German `as.Date("13 März 2020", format = '%d %B %Y')` gives the correct "2020-03-13". To check your locale you could do `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")`. And a possible fix would be to switch to an English locale for the converting the dates.

Comment: `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` returns `"zh_CN.UTF-8"` for my laptop.

Comment: I just added `dput(head(df, 5))`, @Benson_YoureFired

Comment: [strptime, as.POSIXct and as.Date return unexpected NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na)

Comment: `df %>% mutate(date=strptime(date, '%d %B %Y'))`? It returns `<POSIXlt>`s for the whole column

Comment: ahbon, what happens when you follow the code in Henrik's linked answer? Something like `loc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C") ; head(as.Date(df$date, format="%d %B %Y")); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", loc)`

Comment: It works, but is it possible to set it in pipe? @r2evans

Comment: try `... %>% withr::with_locale(new=c(LC_TIME="C"), as.Date(as.Date(date, format = '%d %B %Y')))`

Comment: I get an error with your code. It seems we should use: `withr::with_locale(new=c(LC_TIME="C"), df %>% mutate(date=as.Date(date, format="%d %B %Y")))`

Comment: `df %>% withr::with_locale(new=c(LC_TIME="C"), as.Date(as.Date(date, format = '%d %B %Y')))` returns`Error in withr::with_locale(., new = c(LC_TIME = "C"), as.Date(as.Date(date, :
   The parameter is not used (as.Date(as.Date(date, format = "%d %B %Y")))`.