# POSIXlt object showing NA values after conversion

Tags: r, datetime-format, na, timestamp-with-timezone, posixlt

I am trying to add ride length calculation to all_trips data frame in seconds. To do that I have to use `difftime()` function and also convert `start_time` and `end_time` colunms to POSIXlt objects before calculating the time difference.

During my conversion of `start_time` and `end_time` columns to POSIXlt objects I get `NA` values as the POSIXlt format

This is what I tried:

```
all_trips$start_time <- as.POSIXlt(all_trips$start_time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
all_trips$end_time <- as.POSIXlt(all_trips$end_time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
```

My expectation:

```
start_time: POSIXlt, format: "2023-01-01 12:00:00" "2023-01-02 13:00:00" ...
end_time  : POSIXlt, format: "2023-01-01 12:30:00" "2023-01-02 13:30:00" ...
```

My actual result:

```
start_time: POSIXlt[1:5723606], format: NA NA NA ...
end_time  : POSIXlt[1:5723606], format: NA NA NA ...
```

My data:

```
  trip_id          bikeid        start_time   end_t…¹ from_…² from_…³ to_st…⁴ to_st…⁵ user_…⁶
  <chr>            <chr>         <chr>        <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 9340B064F0AEE130 electric_bike 7/23/2023 2… 7/23/2… Kedzie… 20204   Public… 877     member 
2 D1460EE3CE0D8AF8 classic_bike  7/23/2023 1… 7/23/2… Wester… KA1504… Milwau… 13033   member 
3 DF41BE31B895A25E classic_bike  7/23/2023 1… 7/23/2… Wester… KA1504… Damen … TA1305… member 
4 9624A293749EF703 electric_bike 7/21/2023 8… 7/21/2… Racine… 13155   Clinto… TA1305… member 
5 2F68A6A4CDB4C99A classic_bike  7/8/2023 15… 7/8/20… Clark … TA1309… Montro… TA1308… member 
6 9AEE973E6B941A9C classic_bike  7/10/2023 8… 7/10/2… Racine… 13155   Sangam… TA1306… member
```

Comment: Can you give an excerpt of the `all_trips` object with `dput(all_trips)` (or `dput(head(all_trips))` if the dataframe is too large)?

Comment: This is a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na) that almost certainly has to do with your formatting, although you didnt share your data so cant tell what the exact issue is. But your expectation is "2023-01-01 12:00:00" yet your formatting includes slashes (\\) not dashes (-) and doesn't include seconds

Comment: Try `strptime("7/23/2023 19:29:08", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`.

Comment: Could you try sharing data so that we can see a whole timestamp? `dput()` is nicest, as Julien suggests, as it is copypasteable. What you have shared without `dput` looks like `7/23/2023 2…`, which isn't complete.